# How to move files in a folder to a different folder in c++

Tags: c++, file, netbeans, copy-paste, file-rename

I have a lot of .jpg images in my folder called "pics" and I want to copy all of these pictures and move them to my new folder I made called "PicsSelected".I have researched ways to do this and the easiest method to do this is by using the rename() function. For visual purposes, this is what I want to do (I'm working in Netbeans):
[image]

So far, this is what I have in my main method:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string copyFrom = "C:\\Users\pwhit\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MoveFiles\pics";
    string pasteTo = "C:\\Users\pwhit\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MoveFiles\PicsSelected";
    rename(copyFrom.c_str(), pasteTo.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

The project runs but when I check the 'PicsSelected' folder, it remains empty. Why are the contents of my 'pics' folder not being moved to the destination folder? Am I using the wrong syntax? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `rename()` renames a single file or a directory. It doesn't automatically move files from one directory to another one, as you seem to think it does. And if you bothered to check the return value from `rename()`, you would've been aware that it failed.

Answer (score 0):

rename works on individual file, Run a loop over all the files in the directory to get the required result. The target however should just be the target directory name.
It is very similar to the unix rename command.

Answer (score 0):

What you are moving is the folder.

So I think if your final string is "...\MoveFiles\PicsSelected\pics" your folder "pics" should be inside "PicsSelected" then.

I used rename in Ubuntu and the experience was this worked.